# Keep old returned Ajax data in div instead of overwriting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to update a section of my website, it is all working great at the moment and updating a div with the response data I get back.

However, at the moment it is just replacing the text in the div everytime I keep submitting the ajax form, what I want is for the data to stay and just keep adding on underneath with the data returned from the ajax request. Here is the code

**Html**

```
<form id="foo">

<label for="bar">A bar</label>
<input id="bar" name="bar" type="text" value="" />

<input type="submit" value="Send" />
```

```
<br /><br /><br /><div id="testarea" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: #9f1717; color: #fff;"></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#foo").submit(function() {

        var url = "new_shout_ajax_test.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $("#foo").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
               success: function(data)
               {
                   //alert(data); // show response from the php script.
                   $('#testarea').text(data);
               }
             });

        return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
});
```

**Code in the new_shout_ajax_test.php**

```
$bar = $_POST['bar'];
echo $bar;
```

Basically I want the data to return like this

```
Ajax request 1 Data
Ajax request 2 Data
Ajax request 3 Data
```

Instead of keep getting overwritten by the new data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.append() is what you're looking for

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#foo").submit(function() {

        var url = "new_shout_ajax_test.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $("#foo").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
               success: function(data)
               {


        //alert(data); // show response from the php script.
               $('#testarea').append(data);
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

});

Comment: thats great, although i was wondering is there anyway for the data to append before the previous data, rather than after it?

Comment: .prepend() here are your options: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/

Answer (score 0):

Just this :

```
$('#testarea').append(data);  // Append the next data from ajax to the previous
```